# I want my robot.txt to allow indexing of only my index file in google. How does this look?

Tags: robots.txt

I want my robot.txt to allow indexing of only my index file in google.  How does this look?  Will the following do the trick?

```
User-agent: Google
Disallow: /_/
Disallow: /library/
Disallow: /media/
Disallow: /www/

User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try this**

```
    User-agent: Google
    Disallow: /
    Allow: /index.php
    Allow: /$ #this will allow your homepage as well**
```

**but its better to use htaccess redirect , to redirect example.com to example.com/index.php. To avoid duplication of url.

Comment: Also, will google index http://example.com/ or http://example.com/index.php or both?

Comment: it will work only for index.php witch is best practice , coz you are avoiding duplication. check the edited one now